# In Pycharm, how to move my cursor cell by cell?

Tags: python, pycharm

As you know, I can move my cursor using keyboard arrow keys.
In Matlab and Spyder, I can move my cursor cell by cell using Ctrl + up arrow or Ctrl + down arrow

How can I do that in Pycharm??

--added
To describe my question, I added screenshots. Please see the location of cursor on each screenshot. I would like to move my cursor like that at once.

[image: cell 1]

[image: cell 2]

Comment: Maybe try with `Shift-Alt-Up/Down`.

Comment: Did you not get *any* help from the PyCharm documentation?  When I did a trivial search I got a *lot* of useful-looking hits.

Comment: @PApostol Thanks for comment. However, Shift-Alt-Up/Down <-- this command moves 'code' up and down, instead of my cursor.

Comment: @Prune  I already did. I have no idea why I can't find this shortcuts though I think it is very simple and essential things.

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots.  I've retracted my closure vote and reversed my down-vote.  I'm not a frequent PyCharm user by any means.  I expect that you've tried all of the LShift-RShift-Alt-Ctrl-Flower-arrow combinations.  You might also try Tab and F3/F5 for navigation?

Comment: Found half answer. I think it is impossible to do it in normal Pycharm. However, if I open jupyter in Pycharm, I can move cell by cell using ctrl+arrow.